# Write dynamic Checkbox to table using values from another table

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

Current summary of the problem: I am pulling in information from table 'main' that lists out Goal Number and Goal Name for a specific ID (there can be up to 10 rows). These are displayed in a table on the web page. I added checkboxes in the first column that reflect the amount of rows in the table. The code for this is below, this part is working correctly. The out put is 3 columns, Checkbox, Goal Number, Goal Name, and up to 10 rows depending on amount of information in the table for that specific ID.

goals.php

```
<tr>
        <td valign=top colspan=3>
            Current Goals<br>
                <?php
                //this data is being pulled from 'main'
                    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM main WHERE idnumber = $idnumber ORDER BY goalnumber");
                    if ($result) {
                    $total_rows = mysql_numrows($result);
                    } else { $total_rows = 0; }
                    print "<table border=1 width=400>\n";
                    print "<tr> \n";
                    print "<th> Checkbox </th> \n";
                    print "<th> Goal Number </th> \n";
                    print "<th> Goal Name </th> \n";
                    print "</tr> \n";
                    //}
                    $i = 0;
                    while ( $i < $total_rows )
                    {
                    $goalno = intval(mysql_result($result, $i, "goalnumber"));
                    $goalname = mysql_result($result, $i, "goalname");
                    $goal_id = intval(mysql_result($result, $i, "goal_id"));
                    print "<tr> \n";
                    print "<td> <center><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"goal_id_$i\" value=\"$goalnumber - $goalname\"></td> \n";
                    print "<td> $goalnumber </td> \n";
                    print "<td> $goalname </td> \n";
                    print "</tr> \n";
                    $i = $i + 1;
                    }
                ?>
                </table>
        </td>
```

Once a user checks anywhere from 1-10 of these checkboxes and submits the form, I need to pass the values of said selections to the db (each selection should be written to a new field in the db table 'updated_goals'. On submit the below file gets called. Note that I am writing the checkbox value to a different table in the same db 'updated_goals'. I am not sure where I am going wrong with the code, but the goal is to write the values of the checkbox, "$goalnumber - $goalname" into the goal_id field.

goals_submit.php

```
// process data in table: updated_goals
$query = "SELECT idnumber from updated_goals where idnumber = {$_POST['idnumber']}";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$total_rows = mysql_numrows($result);

            //writing data to 'updated_goals'

        if (isset($_POST ['goal_id_$i'])) { $goal_id = ReplaceQuotes($_POST['goal_id_$i']); } else { $goal_id = ""; }

    $query = "INSERT INTO updated_goals ( ";
    $query .= "goal_id ";
    $query .= ") VALUES ( ";
    $query .= "'$goal_id' ";
    $query .= ")";
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Have you tried echoing `$query` to see what the query is?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: why you used $_POST['goal_id'][$i]? it must be $_POST['goald_id_$id']; you considered that the checkbox name is name="goal_id[$i]" but its not.

Comment: The error I am getting is 'Notice: Undefined variable: i in \goals_submit.php on line 34' which is the 'if (isset' statement above. The query is:  
 // process data in table: medsocial
 $query = "SELECT stid from medicaid where stid = {$_POST['stid']}";
 $result = mysql_query($query);
 $total_rows = mysql_numrows($result);

There is other information that is writing correctly on the form, the checkboxes are the only thing not working. It is removing the 'null' value in the table and replacing it with a blank ''

Comment: @AkamOmer has the correct answer then. He just needs to add it as an answer.

Comment: @AkamOmer that worked to remove the error but it isn't passing the value to the table, just passing ''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solutions:

Change this line:

```
if (isset($_POST ['goal_id'][$i])) { $goal_id = ReplaceQuotes($_POST['goal_id'][$i]); } else { $goal_id = ""; }
```

to

```
if (isset($_POST ['goal_id_'.$i])) { $goal_id = ReplaceQuotes($_POST['goal_id_'.$i]); } else { $goal_id = ""; }
```

or
change this line

```
print "<td> <center><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"goal_id_$i\" value=\"$goalnumber - $goalname\"></td> \n";
```

to

```
print "<td> <center><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"goal_id[$i]\" value=\"$goalnumber - $goalname\"></td> \n";
```

if array used for input name for example:
inputname[]
it can be get via POST or GET by $_POST['inputname'][index] or $_GET['inputname'][index]

Comment: I went with your first option changing the if (isset statement and am still getting the error:
Notice: Undefined variable: i in \goals_submit.php on line 36

If I change to the following from your first comment,

if (isset($_POST ['goal_id_$i'])) { $goal_id = ReplaceQuotes($_POST['goal_id_$i']); } else { $goal_id = ""; }

The error goes away but no value is passed to the table

Comment: ok, use print_r($_POST) to see if the values there? and also echo $query to see if the query is complete? you can also update your first post with what you tried.

Comment: With print_r($_POST) getting the following error

'Notice: Undefined index: goal_id_$i in \goals_submit.php on line 38

Notice: Undefined index: goal_id_$i in \goals_submit.php on line 38'

Where line 38 is the statement we are working on

Comment: Ok, we expect $i to be a variable? yes: its interpreted as text, please can you paste full code of what you tried?

Comment: Sorry I misspoke. Here is the result of the print_r($_POST)

`Array ( [idnumber] => 123456 [goal_id_1] => 1 - PLOP/Math [progress] => Progress Made [unit] => testing 1 [activity] => ox [plan] => Continue [assessment] => testing 2 )`

This is showing the value for goal_id being passed to the db but it is not showing when I call up the table in the db, all the other values show in the table.

Comment: I had a syntax error elsewhere in my code that I corrected and it worked. Thank you for your patience and your help!